# Selecting work days using python 2.7 time series

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to work on stocks from a certain time period using only month end dates ( barring any holidays etc).

Here is my code:

```
aapl = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start, end)
bbry = web.DataReader("BBRY", "yahoo", start, end)

stocks = pd.DataFrame({"AAPL": aapl["Adj Close"],
                      "BBRY": bbry["Adj Close"],
                    }, pd.date_range(start, end, freq='BM'))

stocks.head()
```

However I am not certain that it is including only the month end days when the the markets were open.

Any help is appreciated.

I am using python2.7

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach:

```
In [188]: import pandas_datareader.data as web
     ...:
     ...: stocklist = ['AAPL','BBRY','LULU','AMZN']
     ...: p = web.DataReader(stocklist, 'yahoo', '2011-11-01', '2012-04-01')
     ...: p['Adj Close'].resample('M').last()
     ...:
Out[188]:
                 AAPL        AMZN       BBRY       LULU
Date
2011-11-30  49.987684  192.289993  17.860001  49.700001
2011-12-31  52.969683  173.100006  14.500000  46.660000
2012-01-31  59.702715  194.440002  16.629999  63.130001
2012-02-29  70.945373  179.690002  14.170000  67.019997
2012-03-31  78.414750  202.509995  14.700000  74.730003
```